# XML data bases and ORM

Tags: .net, xml, mapping, orm

A few years ago I used the Hibernate ORM for mapping database data to the objects and manipulate it. Currently I have xml database and the next question, Is there  orm for the xml databases or something like this?
**It is my mistake I did not put technology**, I need ORM for .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JOXM](http://code.google.com/p/joxm/)

Comment: Something like this but for .net

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Hibernate for that. Haven't tried it though.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html

Comment: Yes, I can, but Hibernate is to big, I need something lighter than Hibernate and yes for .net